# ggplot2- Multiple line plot sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset where individuals increase in value over time and have a status of 1 or 0. I can plot a line for each individuals increase over time, colouring the lines depending upon whether they are a 0 or a 1.

I can't figure out though how to then have all the 0's plotted on top of all the 1s so that the zeros don't have any 1's going over the top of them.

I have assigned them to groups and then set the group order and tried to plot by group but that doesn't work.

To demonstrate the problem, I can use the ChickWeight dataset. If I plot using the following script then the grey lines are on top of the blue, I want to be able to plot them still using blue for chick 1 but the blue lines to be on top of the grey ones.

```
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Chick))+
geom_point(aes(colour=Diet,shape=Diet),size=1.5)+
geom_line(aes(colour=Diet,group=Chick))+
scale_colour_manual(values=c('blue','grey','grey','grey'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to do a double geoms to control plotting order:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, group=Chick, shape=Diet))+
    geom_line(data = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Diet != '1', ])+
    geom_line(data = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Diet == '1', ])+
    geom_point(size=1.5, data = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Diet != '1', ])+
    geom_point(size=1.5, data = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Diet == '1', ])+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('blue','grey','grey','grey'))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you get better result if you change the geom order to 1) line then point for grey, followed by 2) line then point for blue

Comment: @dww, ah yes that's true. The principle should be clear though.